# How to determine average values for Wednesdays in august and highest closing price on days except one

Tags: python, pandas

How to solve this in Pandas

1. Subset the August data into a new dataframe. Display the average values for Wednesdays in August.
2. What is the highest closing price in August on a day that is NOT Wednesday?

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
6/7/2018,190.75,190.970001,186.770004,188.179993,21503200
6/8/2018,187.529999,189.479996,186.429993,189.100006,12677100
6/11/2018,188.809998,192.600006,188.800003,191.539993,12928900
6/12/2018,192.169998,193.279999,191.559998,192.399994,11562700
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the original data as it did not contain August or Wednesdays

```
df.Date = df.Date.astype('datetime64')
print('All data\n', df, sep='')
newdf = df[df.Date.dt.month.eq(8)]
print('\nAugust data\n', newdf, sep='')
print('\nAverage values for Wednesdays in August\n',
      newdf[newdf.Date.dt.dayofweek.eq(2)].mean(numeric_only=True), sep='')
print('\nHighest closing price in August on a day that is NOT Wednesday\n',
      newdf.loc[newdf.Date.dt.dayofweek.ne(2), 'Close'].max(), sep='')
```

Prints:

```
All data
        Date        Open        High         Low       Close    Volume
0 2018-08-07  190.750000  190.970001  186.770004  188.179993  21503200
1 2018-08-08  187.529999  189.479996  186.429993  189.100006  12677100
2 2018-08-15  188.809998  192.600006  188.800003  191.539993  12928900
3 2018-07-12  192.169998  193.279999  191.559998  192.399994  11562700

August data
        Date        Open        High         Low       Close    Volume
0 2018-08-07  190.750000  190.970001  186.770004  188.179993  21503200
1 2018-08-08  187.529999  189.479996  186.429993  189.100006  12677100
2 2018-08-15  188.809998  192.600006  188.800003  191.539993  12928900

Average values for Wednesdays in August
Open      1.881700e+02
High      1.910400e+02
Low       1.876150e+02
Close     1.903200e+02
Volume    1.280300e+07
dtype: float64

Highest closing price in August on a day that is NOT Wednesday
188.179993
```